# Sails.js v 10.2 missing express app

Tags: express, sails.js

How can we access express app instance from Sails global object after upgrade?

When in sails.0.9x we can access express app instance by

sails.express.app

after upgrading to 0.10, the express function is missing

How can we call the app?

Our test case failed since using supertest, how can we fixed the sails.express.app problem

```
var request = require("supertest");

describe("TestController", function() {
  describe(".plain", function () {
    it("returns 200 with status done", function(done) {
      request(sails.express.app)
        .get("/test/plain")
        .expect(200, { status: "done" })
        .expect("Content-Type", /json/)
        .end(function(err, res) {
          if (err) return done(err);
          done();
        });
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Sails v0.10 the underlying HTTP server (i.e. the Express app) is available as:

```
sails.hooks.http.app
```

Comment: Thanks, able to work now. Would be good if any document support on this

Comment: or, as mentioned above, sails.express.app for previous versions