# sails.js: how to disable etags

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, etag

I read this not very new [post](http://qzaidi.github.io/2013/07/20/surprises/) about disabling some things in sails.js. Specifically what I would like to try out is the disabling of etags.

Does anyone know how to disable that in sails.js (0.11.0)?

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25179341/sails-js-v-10-2-missing-express-app) to access to the express app. It should be `sails.hooks.http.app.disable(‘etag’)`

Comment: @AlexisN-o: where should this kind of initialization be put?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could disable it in [the `bootstap.js` file](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/config/bootstrap-js):

```js
// config/bootstrap.js
module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {

  // Add this line to access to the Express app and disable etags
  sails.hooks.http.app.disable('etag');

  // It's very important to trigger this callback method when you are finished
  // with the bootstrap!  (otherwise your server will never lift, since it's waiting on the bootstrap)
  cb();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is only for dynamic files. For static files, you must override the www middleware by adding this code to the config/https.js file

```
www: (function() {
  var flatFileMiddleware = require('serve-static')('.tmp/public', {
    maxAge: 31557600000,
    etag: false
  });

  return flatFileMiddleware;
})(),
```

The maxAge has to be there if you still want to set the cache-control header with an age. Also note that this will override the cache option in the same http.js file used to define that age.

For my purpose, I only wanted to remove the etags from the static files served up in the /min folder, which are the minified css and js files. So to do this I had to define a route in the routes.js file

```
'get /min/*': { 
  skipAssets: false,
  fn: [
    require('serve-static')('.tmp/public', {
      maxAge: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 0 : 31557600000,
      etag: false
    }),
  ]
}
```

If you want more of the details, see here https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/5306#issuecomment-508239510.