# Remove etag from sailsjs

Tags: sails.js

I'm trying to remove *etag* http header in my application. I followed the [answer posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32067991/sails-js-how-to-disable-etags). Solution makes total sense! I also know my sails variable is global and working. However I can't get;

```
sails.hooks.http.app.disable('etag');
```

and/or

```
sails.hooks.http.app.set('etag', false);
```

to work even though they are in [bootstrap.js](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/anatomy/my-app/config/bootstrap-js) file. Etags are still showing up??? am I missing something here?

(I'm on sails version 0.12.3)

Comment: sails.hooks.http.app.disable('etag'); works fine when added to bootstrap.js.  But it doestn't remove it from assets.

Comment: @Bonanza can you show documentation that proves that? It doesn't make sense express removes tag headers from response but doesn't remove it from static files. Express serves the static files too.

Comment: i just checked that in mine project. Sails documentation is incomplete. It may be bug if it doesn't remove etag from statics.

Comment: I've added an answer below

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single way to remove etags from both dynamic files and static files in sails. The way you described is for dynamic files. For static files, you must override the www middleware by adding this code to the config/https.js file

```
www: (function() {
  var flatFileMiddleware = require('serve-static')('.tmp/public', {
    maxAge: 31557600000,
    etag: false
  });

  return flatFileMiddleware;
})(),
```

The maxAge has to be there if you still want to set the cache-control header with an age. Also note that this will override the cache option in the same http.js file used to define that age.

For my purpose, I only wanted to remove the etags from the static files served up in the /min folder, which are the minified css and js files. So to do this I had to define a route in the routes.js file

```
'get /min/*': { 
  skipAssets: false,
  fn: [
    require('serve-static')('.tmp/public', {
      maxAge: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 0 : 31557600000,
      etag: false
    }),
  ]
}
```

If you want more of the details, see here https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/5306#issuecomment-508239510.